# How to select the largest index of the smallest element in a single array Java

Tags: java, indexing, element

Basically, I need to find the largest index of the smallest element in an array. The first input is the number of elements. However, if the same number is repeated later in the array, it needs to return that index.

Right now my code finds the smallest number and returns the index of that number. How do I update the index?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class smallestelement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length = input.nextInt();

        int [] a = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
          a[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        // minimum 
        int min = a[0]; 
        // counter
        int index = 0; 
        // loop continues as long as i is less than the length of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){   
              min = a[i];                   
              index = i;
              }
        System.out.println(index);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `if` statement to check if you are really looking at a smaller element. Use `<=` to do the comparison, so that when you see an equally-smallest value, the later index is used.

```java
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {  
    if (a[i] <= min) {
        min = a[i];                   
        index = i;
    }
}
```

By the way, it's fine for the loop to start at 1 instead of 0, since you initialise `min` and `index` before the loop using the value at index 0.